# Run javascript inside HTML component in Adobe AIR Flex 4?

Tags: javascript, html, apache-flex, button, execute

I have the following component in an AIR application from Flex 4:

```
<mx:HTML id="viewObject"
         x="10" y="42" width="634" height="313"
         location="http;//localhost:8080/mypage.php" />
```

Now I want to run a javascript when the page loads but the javascript isn't inside the target page. I want to run the following javascript:

```
javascript:alert('Hello world.');
```

I tried approaching it by setting the **location** property again to the javascript after the page has loaded like below.

```
<s:Button x="10" y="10" label="Button">
    <s:click>
        <![CDATA[
        viewObject.location = "javascript:alert('hello world');";
        ]]>
    </s:click>
</s:Button>
```

Unfortunately for me, that doesn't seem to work. Can anybody help me out with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because location is like using the address bar.  What you need to do is something like this:

```
htmlComponent.htmlLoader.window.alert('hello world');
```

I think that should work.

Comment: what would other arbitrary javascript code look like? for example, how would one call jquery

Comment: You should probably look up `LocalConnection` if you want flash to javascript communication.